# v.clean with rgrass does not work, vector type not found

Tags: grass-gis, rgrass7

I'm trying to clean a vector file called `network` with `rgrass` library using v.clean. Here's my code:

```
Sys.setenv("GRASS_INSTALLATION"="C:/Program Files/GRASS GIS 8.3/")
library(rgrass)
GRASS_INSTALLATION <- Sys.getenv("GRASS_INSTALLATION")
file.info(GRASS_INSTALLATION)$isdir[1]
GRASS_INSTALLATION

td <- tempdir()

test_grass <- initGRASS(gisBase=GRASS_INSTALLATION, home=td, override=TRUE)

write_VECT(terra::vect(network, vname = "network")


# clean
execGRASS(cmd = "v.clean", input = "network",
                 output = "network_clean", tool = "break", 
                 flags = "overwrite")

#check the result
ntwrk = read_VECT("network_clean") |>
  st_as_sf() |>
  st_geometry()


leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
    addPolylines(data=ntwrk)
```

The code works fine until I execute `v.clean`. When I do it, there's a standart Windows notification sound (I don't know how to call it properly), and if I put this execution into a variable and call this variable, the result is 1:

```
test = execGRASS(cmd = "v.clean", input = "network",
                 output = "network_clean", tool = "break", 
                 flags = "overwrite")
test
>>> 1
```

And after that, when I try to check the output of v.clean with leaflet, I get this:

```
Error in read_VECT("network_clean"): Vector type not found
Traceback:

1. st_geometry(st_as_sf(read_VECT("network_clean")))
2. st_as_sf(read_VECT("network_clean"))
3. read_VECT("network_clean")
4. stop("Vector type not found")
```

### How to fix this?

UPD

seems to be I managed to use `v.clean`, I needed to put `flag='o'` in `write_VECT`:
`write_VECT(terra::vect(network_merged[,2:14]), vname = "network_merged", flag='o')`

after that v.clean seems to be working. But after that when I try to check the result I get this error:

```
> ntwrk = read_VECT("network_clean") |>
+   st_as_sf() |>
+   st_geometry()
WARNING: <PROJ_INFO> file not found for location <file5a8c7b217b41>
WARNING: <PROJ_UNITS> file not found for location <file5a8c7b217b41>
ERROR: Unable to create OGR spatial reference
Error: [vect] file does not exist: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi68HTy\file5a8c1118746e.gpkg
```

I found some .gpkg files in the directory that is shown in the error message above, but these are the input files before `v.clean` is executed

Comment: Could you check the vector is not empty?

Comment: @Anna the vector is not empty, I downloaded it from OSM. Here's extract from the sf-object, the file is displayed also correctly on the map https://prnt.sc/FxFjHnGIJ17A

Comment: @Anna please take a look at my update notes in the question, v.clean seems to be working now but I can't find the output file